# Jquery - Reverse animation on click (toggle or if/else)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

*I've tried a lot of different options and I'm sure most would work if I knew what I was doing*.

**I want to click on an image and make it larger and centered in the screen, then I want to click on the same image and return it back to normal.**

In the two individual scripts below I have erased the reverse effect but I basically used functions that changed the css settings back to `width:250, height:250, and marginLeft:9%.` All I could get it to do successfully was enlarge an image but then it shrank automatically once it had fully enlarged. **I need to make the function enlarge and then wait until I click the image again for it to shrink.**

```
<script>

            $('document').ready(function(){
                $('.hello_mom').on('click', function(){
                    $('.lbs_lease').animate({
                        width:"350px",
                        height:"350px",
                        zIndex:"10",
                        marginLeft:"28.4%"
                    }, 500 );
                });
            });

    </script>

    <!--<script>//My idea with this second script was to set an initial variable that I would use to make the enlargement animation run (with an if statement) and the shrinking animation stop until the variable was changed at the end of the function. Once the variable changes the else statement would become true and run my reverse animation. However, it seems redundant when the animation still doesn't wait for another click to occur before it runs.

        $a = 5;
        $c = 10;
        var b = $a;

        if(b < $c) {
            $('.lbs_lease').animate({
                width:"350px",
                height:"350px",
                zIndex:"10",
                marginLeft:"28.4%"
            }, 500 )};

    </script>-->
```

Comment: Use css - toggle a class which makes it bigger, changes margin, changes z-index on click - it's much easier to manage should you need to make changes

Comment: I would use css but I want to build on top of this effect once I have it figured out. My inexperience with jquery doesn't allow me the knowledge to know if using css for this would allow me to efficiently utilize jquery with the rest that I want to do. Basically I want to add elliptical motions during the images re-sizing but only after I figure out how to get my effects to reverse properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 ways to do that ..

1- by using addClass and removeClass with transition

in css

```
.imageClicked{
   width:350px;
   height:350px;
   zIndex:10;
   marginLeft:28.4%;
   transition : 0.5;
}
```

js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('.hello_mom').on('click', function(){
         if($('.lbs_lease').hasClass('imageClicked')){
             $('.lbs_lease').removeClass('imageClicked');  
         }else{
             $('.lbs_lease').addClass('imageClicked');  
         }
     });
});
```

2- by make another animate with default style and use boolean true or false

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var imgClicked = true;
    $('.hello_mom').on('click', function(){
      if(imgClicked == true){ 
         $('.lbs_lease').animate({
                        width:"350px",
                        height:"350px",
                        zIndex:"10",
                        marginLeft:"28.4%"
         }, 500 );
         imgClicked = false;
       }else{
         $('.lbs_lease').animate({
                        //type your default style here
         }, 500 );
         imgClicked = true;
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do, I had all of that nearly to exact syntax but I could not get the variables just right. Thank you!

Comment: @BijanKelley .. glad it helped .. you welcome and Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var left = true;
$('.hello_mom').on('click', function () {
    if (left) {
        $(this).animate({
            'marginLeft': "-=30px"
        });
        left = false;
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            'marginLeft': "+=30px"
        });
        left = true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e1cy8nLm/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ujf6e9u/)

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( 'enlarge' );
});
```

CSS:

```
img {

    // set the initial height and width here so we can animate these properties.
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
}

// toggle this class with jQuery to enlarge the img on click
.enlarge {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods will be using addClass and removeClass jquery functions keeping track of the current state of image.
The `enlarged` variable has the current state of the image and toggles it onclick with addition or removal of class.
Note the transition time is mentioned for both the classes, the added/removed as well as the original styling class to prevent abrupt transition while resizing to both states.

Here is a jsfiddle for that : [**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/327ugjb2/)

HTML Code :

```
<div>
    <img class="hello_mom" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS Code :

```
.hello_mom{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background : red;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hov_class{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    z-index:10;
    //margin-left:28.4%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

JS Code :

```
var enlarged=0;
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.hello_mom').on('click', function(){
        if(!enlarged){
            $('.hello_mom').addClass("hov_class");
            enlarged=1;
        }
        else{
            $('.hello_mom').removeClass("hov_class");
            enlarged=0;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this
http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Velocity is javascript animation, made faster than CSS animation.
...and here you also have a reverse method